# Why does sshd only accept connections from within LAN? (Snow Leopard)

Tags: snow-leopard, ssh

The "server" ("mini", running OSX 10.6) has **SysPrefs>Sharing>RemoteLogin** enabled.  I can log in from another machine on the LAN with `ssh me@mini.local` just fine.  To enable access from WAN, I assigned a static IP address to mini (192.168.1.102) and added a portmapping entry in my TimeCapsule, mapping port 10221 to 192.168.1.102:21.  I have a DynDNS hostname, so I should be able to log in via `ssh -p 10221 me@my.homeip.net` but it just hangs and eventually times out.

I verified that DNS is mapping `my.homeip.net` to my correct public IP address.

Is there another setting on 'mini' that I've overlooked, that allows local connections but disregards non-local ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forwarding to port 21 on your mac mini. SSH uses port 22.

You are also not forced to use a different port on the router: you could map port 22 to 192.168.1.102:22

Comment: Thanks -- that was my mistake (my confusion came from the fact that I'm actually trying to do SFTP).  And yes, I know I can map public 22 instead, but I have several hosts on the LAN that I'll eventually want to connect to, so I'm just adopting a consistent port numbering system.

Comment: @Chap: make sense

Answer (score 0):

Port 21 is reserved for FTP. Why not set the public and private port to 22? Try "the usual way" first to see if it works, then try wacky port numbers if you're truly keen on securing-by-obscuring.

Comment: He is forwarding **to** port 21. So this is typo/mistake not a wrong choice of port.

Comment: @Matteo: correct - just a confusion over SSH and SFTP.  No unusualness intended.